# How to use console log parser in jenkins pipeline project

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am new to jenkins and have build a pipeline project. In one of the stage , I build a docker image and in the next stage , I execute container-structure-test on the docker image . The test cases results can be viewed in the console output.

What I want is in the build summary page , it has a link from where I can directly view the test case results in the logs and need not to go through the complete console output. Since its not junit test cases , I could not find any straight out of the box jenkins plugin.

I came across console log parser plugin but I'm not sure how to use in jenkins declarative pipeline project . I see this option in free style project under post build action but no such option is available in pipeline project.

Could someone suggest me how I can make use of this plugin in pipeline builds to address my usecase.

Answer (score 1):

Here is official documentation mentioning which method you should use:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/log-parser/

You can use it anywhere, but probably you would like to use it at the end of the pipeline in the post phase.

Example:

```
pipeline {
  // some stages here
  
  post {
    always { 
      logParser ([
        projectRulePath: 'path/to/rules/file/on/the/node',
        parsingRulesPath: '',
        showGraphs: true, 
        unstableOnWarning: true, 
        useProjectRule: true
      ])
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins you can use "Generate Code Snippet" which is found at the bottom of your pipeline which allows you to select a number of plugins installed and make a pipeline snippet to copy into your Jenkins pipeline script.

However, with Log Parser as of 2023 an old bug was reopened as the snippet is generated with a compile error for Log Parser plugin making it not work and fail with **"Log Parser Failed"**.

The error is due to missing the following code

```
parsingRulesPath: ''
```

Adding this following code will fix the generated snippet code and allow the parser plugin to work properly with Jenkins declarative pipeline.
Please Note: you may not use the Log Parser options you made in Jenkins\Global Config. The code snippet tool will initially look like you should from the drop-down list, however Jenkins declarative pipeline will error with **"Invalid Path"**

If you encounter invalid path due to using the code snippet generation change it from

```
ProjectRulePath /myRegex/
```

To

`projectRulePath: "path/to/rules/file/on/the/node"`

Utilizing Maverix comment will give you the proper format for Jenkins and log parser.

As for the file you're pathing to it is a .txt and the content is well documented on the plugin [page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/log-parser/) and it can utilize regex.

Comment: I've edited my comment and turned it into an answer for those encountering issues with Log Parser on Jenkins declarative Pipeline in 2023 - which has recently had a bug reopened. I also answer how to utilize any number of plugins with the code snippet tool Jenkins provides. I also made sure to link to the documentation on how to set up the file for Log Parser as it will not function with declarative pipeline without this.

Comment: Thank you. It would probably be appreciated if you keep the reference that you are building on an existing answer (this does not make the post a comment, just gives credit).  Thanks for your reaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can write out the container running log to a file, then publish this file as report.

```
stage('Test') {
  steps {
    script {
      out = sh(returnStdout: true,
               script: '''
                docker run ......
               '''
              )

      writeFile text: out, file: 'test.log'

      publishHTML([
        allowMissing: true, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false, 
        includes: 'test.log', keepAll: false, 
        reportDir: '.', reportFiles: 'test.log', 
        reportName: 'HTML Report'
      ])    
    }
  }
}
```